# npm ETIMEDOUT error when installing package through npm or yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, networking

I am in arch linux . Recently I have **deleted** the npm cache also other cache in my mechine. I got this error in below when i run `npm ping` or installing anything through `npm or yarn`

```js
npm notice PING http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/-/ping?write=true failed, reason:
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/raihan/.npm/_logs/2024-01-09T13_43_18_767Z-debug-0.log
```

After googling this error and visiting stackoverflow and github issues . I saw everyone has solved this issue with their own way . Some way were common . Such as removing the `http-proxy` , `https-proxy` . Resetting the npm registry from https to http . Some solved by remove the npm cache . Some were abled to solve by disable ipv6 .
I have seen issue in github but their solution is not worked for me. I did everything said in above method but nothing worked . But after disabling ipv6 `npm ping` worked and npm worked finely for only one time later i alaways got this error message using yarn or npm . I have also removed node and installed via nvm .I have also changed the version but nothing worked .
node version `21.5.0`
npm version `10.2.4`
arch version `6.6.8-arch1-1`

Comment: I have seen other solution in stackoveflow tried to solve with those method but can't solve

Answer (score 0):

Ok.After upgrading the full system today the problem is solved.